# Building a PHP CSV Staggered Uploader

Tags: javascript, php, csv

I have a CSV File which has about 2500 columns and 25,000 rows. I need to build a PHP interface to upload the file to a database. The database is Cassandra which nativity supports amount of data without an issue.

I realize that this would take a very long time...... but at the moment that is not an issue.

I'm a little bit unsure of the best way to proceed. My first instinct was to build a java-script client which simply gives the offset and limit to a php script which uploads the data, 5 rows at a time. This would allow for a visual progress bar for the user and would avoid PHP time outs however I'm yet to find a good way to have offsets with csv. Any ifelse methods seem to timeout before the records are even found.

Do you have any suggestions? Feel free to suggest a different language or method, but the method needs to work through a PHP application that the user can access.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers dont provide any facility for incremental file uploading - its all done in one shot. If you want progress bars you can use tools like Uploadify:

http://www.uploadify.com/

Either way you're going to have to do the upload all at once. By the time your HTTP server hands the request off to PHP, PHP will have access to the complete file.

If you need incremental file uploading you might have to write your own uploader in Java Applet or Flash.

Comment: No - I'm not talking about file upload - I'm talking about database upload. The file is already on the server (Or a separate service like the one you have suggested will be used to get it there) but PHP can't handle a file that size in one hit.

Comment: Ok, so the file is already accessible to PHP. Then just use `fgetcsv` to read the file in chunks and insert into your datastore: http://us3.php.net/fgetcsv